# How to display my calendar on the lock screen?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, lock-screens, calendar, app-widgets, sony-xperia-arc

What is the best way to show (non-interactive) widgets on the lock screen?

I have bought WidgetLocker, but it forces me to unlock the screen twice (using both WidgetLocker and native slider).

(Using Android 2.3.2 on a Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc.)

Comment: Can you disable the stock lock screen and only use WidgetLocker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lockscreen Calendar](https://market.android.com/details?id=de.j4velin.lockscreenCalendar&feature=search_result) is a fairly lightweight app to display your next few upcoming events on your lockscreen.

Unfortunately, it does not currently support recurring events.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this application will help You;
http://www.appbrain.com/app/executive-assistant/com.appventive.ExecAssist

It's pretty expensive but looks pretty powerful.

Comment: Unfortunately This app is currently not available on Playstore or the link you have mentioned. So you can remove/update your answer so it dont get downvotes..

Answer (score 0):

Probably Damian gave you the best answer. An alternative I could suggest is, if you have rooted your phone, consider trying [MIUI ROM](http://miuiandroid.com/) cause the new version (1.6) has the a [theming lockscreen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QZILW67QXU&feature=player_embedded#at=38) with already dozens of available themes and tweaks. Maybe you find what your looking for there.