# Displaying the lock-screen clock on the home screen

Tags: lock-screens, clock, sony-xperia-arc

I'm having a problem opposite to [How to display my calendar on the lock screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8516/how-to-display-my-calendar-on-the-lock-screen).

I absolutely love the clock I see on the lock-screen (Xperia Arc S (LT18i), Android 2.3.4):

[image]

Very nice appearance, and displays day of week in full. I'm very used to it since my previous phone, Xperia X8.
I want this clock on my home page (as it used to be on Xperia X8).

But when I add it as a widget, I get that:

[image]

Much smaller font and no day of week. And I can't seem to find any settings for it.

Google Play tells me the clock is [Digi Clock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonyericsson.digitalclockwidget), and it confirms it's that clock that is installed on my X8. I can't install it ("already installed"), I can't remove it (system app) and I can't update it (no updates available).

So how do I make that clock appear in the same way on both the lock-screen and the home screen?

Answer (score 1):

The clock shown on the lock screen is part of the lock screen itself. The clock on your home screen is a widget.

The only way to get the lock screen clock on your home screen is to find a widget that looks the same. There are plenty of widgets on the Google Play store, and if you can't find one you like you could always write one yourself!