# Cyanogenmod 12: How to display calendar events on lock screen?

Tags: cyanogenmod, lock-screens, calendar, lock-screen-widgets

Seems fairly basic, and this has been working well with CM11, but however, 
**with CM12 I have not managed to configure the lock screen to show the next couple of events,** without having to unlock.

I have

- A Samsung Galaxy S II (Yeah, still my preferred device)
- Cyanogenmod cm-12.1-20151116
- The pico OpenGapps package
- a PIN to unlock

I really loved the highly customizable lock screen of CM11 and it seems to be gone... Do I really need to install a lock screen app, like chronus (Is it no more packaged by default?)

*Note: my question regards a different OS version than [this one.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8516/how-to-display-my-calendar-on-the-lock-screen)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app you are looking for is cLock. Its a widget and its still present in CyanogenMod.

Unfortunatelly, from Lollipop onwards, you can't put any widgets on your lock screen, and by that you are unable to use the described widget as you used it before.

Hovever, you can still place it on your home screen.

Comment: Did they really remove that feature entirely – or is that only when you've defined a pin/pattern/password lock? cLock ships with CM, so it's a system app I'd think capable (and authorized) to do this. If not, that's an argument against upgrading to me: I've just loved this feature! I thought cLock *was* CM's lock screen app?

Comment: It is still there, in the same form. The only thing that has changed is the ability to put this (or any other) widget on your lock screen. Having a pin, pattern or something else doesnt make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Chapz! May I suggest to integrate those details directly with your answer, so we can remove the comments? Gets more "obvious" that way.

Comment: I edited the answer, I think it sums it up now. If you accept it as an answer it will be get the focus of people with similar problems.

Comment: Thanks Chapz! I've upvoted it – but accepting can only be done by OP :)